# Animated toggle columns

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page containing a table, in which i have three columns with `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`. When clicking a cell in the adjacent column, the attributes change to `table-cell` and `visible` respectively, showing the three columns. Another click at the cell of said adjacent column resets the values to `none` and `hidden`.

The only problem is that, of course, it's not pleasant to see. I would like to include an animation so that i can see the other columns shrink in order to let the hidden columns slide in the middle and an animation when i can do the opposite thing.

What should I use? I'm asking for help because I'm relatively new to web designing and I have no idea about where to look for guidance.

Comment: you can use jQuery toggle().. Here is a sample one https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_toggle

Answer (score 1):

The tables themselves are not animated. Perhaps this option may suit you. (Google translate.)

```js
$('.show').on('click', function(){
 $('.table').find('.td').each(function(){
   if($(this).css('display') === 'none'){
     $(this).show().addClass('animate');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.table{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.td{
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tr{
  display: flex;
}

.td{
  padding: 10px;
}
.td:nth-of-type(2){
  display: none;
}
*{
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
button{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.animate{
  animation: show 1s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes show{
  from{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    display: block;
  }
  to{
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">1</div>
    <div class="td">2</div>
    <div class="td">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">1</div>
    <div class="td">2</div>
    <div class="td">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">1</div>
    <div class="td">2</div>
    <div class="td">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="show">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as I finished posting the question, a friend of mine introduced me to the `fadeToggle` function available using JQuery. This is precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: There's also slideToggle function it gives another animation, give it a try ;)